# SwiftUI: How do you change the tint color (background color) of a NavigationView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a NavigationView with a List in it. How do I change the color of the NavigationView?

Answer (score 4):

**there is no direct api(yet)** to do this, but you can look at the debug view hierarchy and you will see that it is a simple UINavigationBar and all of the old solutions would work here too(yet).

```
struct ContentView: View {

init(){
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
}
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Text("1")
            Text("2")
            Text("3")
            Text("4")
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Title With Red Color"))
    }
}
```

}

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: But this answer  for UINavigationBar. Question or problem for just NavigationView.

Comment: I'm having problems with this too, that the proposed answer doesn't solve. I'm getting a gray background color when I embed a List in a  NavigationView. I'd rather not have that gray background.