# How to change background color of the NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change background color of the NavigationView (not navigation bar) using this code:

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Text")
}
.background(Color.clear)
```

But it doesn't work.
Also, I tried to change UIView appearance:

```
UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

But it doesn't work too.

The actual result is presented below:

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI: How do you change the tint color (background color) of a NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503479/swiftui-how-do-you-change-the-tint-color-background-color-of-a-navigationview)

Comment: @IIya Please check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61812677/change-background-color-of-view-inside-tabview-having-navigationview-and-scrollv?noredirect=1#comment109334412_61812677]

Comment: @IIya - Did you find a solution ?? Even i have a view which is behind NavigationView and I want to make it visible my setting Navigation View background as clear color .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First look at this result:

[image: View hierarchy]

As you can see, you can set the color of each element in the View hierarchy like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init(){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .green 
        //For other NavigationBar changes, look here:(https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509555/5623035)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    Color.blue
                    Text("Some text")
                }
            }.background(Color.red)
        }
        // iOS 16 - No need for tweaking the appearance
        /* .toolbarBackground(.green, in: .navigationBar) */
    }
}
```

And the first one is `window`:

```
window.backgroundColor = .magenta
```

The issue you faced is we can not remove the background color of SwiftUI's `HostingViewController` (yet), so you can't see the `navigationView` (What you called) through the views hierarchy. You should wait for the API or try to fake the navigation view (**not recommended**).

Comment: I want to change the background color of the NavigationView, not the UINavigationBar

Comment: What do you mean `navigationView`? you mean the entire view inside the navigation?

Comment: You mean that background image?

Comment: The background image is placed under the NavigationView.

Comment: There seems to be no solution at the moment. I tried everything I knew, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not yet @Maddiee. Also, Apple removes some of our workarounds too. ‍♂️