# Change background color of View inside TabView having NavigationView and ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to build a `TabView` with 4 tabs having collection views in it. Below is my code of one tab named 'Gallery'.

> 

```
 var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                GridStack(rows: 3, columns: 2) { row, column, totalColumn in
                    CardView(card: self.cards[(row * totalColumn) + column])
                }.padding().background(Color.red)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Gallery")
        }
    }
```

When I give background color for `ScrollView`, scrolling is not working for `NavigationView` largeTitle. How can I achieve this, I want to give red color for full view's background? What if I need to achieve this same backgorund color for all tabs?

[image]

Comment: Did you try with `ZStack` and putting color behind?

Comment: yeah!! But got issue in scrolling @EnesKaraosman

Comment: @EnesKaraosman Can we manage scrolling of NavigationView largeTitle, if we use ZStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach (scroll view is not broken in such case)

```
NavigationView {
    GeometryReader { gp in
        ScrollView {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.red) // << background

              // ... your content here, internal alignment might be needed

            }.frame(minHeight: gp.size.height)

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Gallery")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi it's working, given `ZStack(alignment: .top)` solved alignment issue.